# How to use the powshell to call the Graph API, such as get the user's data?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I learn from the stack overflow, that show we can using the PowerShell to call some  URL. So I want to use the PowerShell to call the Graph API for testing. So anyone can provide a sample code to show how to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up your environment to use the MSGraph API first for your needs...

[There are several steps to get this done as documented on the MS Docs and TechNet sites](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/cloudlojik/2017/09/05/using-powershell-to-connect-to-microsoft-graph-api/)

... then use the PSMSGraph module to interact with it.

[There are many more docs like the above on the topic](https://thelazyadministrator.com/2018/03/20/connect-to-the-microsoft-graph-api-with-powershell/). Once you get all setup, then you can move forward as noted.

Connect to the Graph API

Each time you want to connect to the Microsoft Graph API you will need to export the AccessToken.

```
$GraphAccessToken = Import-GraphOAuthAccessToken -Path 'c:\MyGraphApp\AccessToken.XML'
$GraphAccessToken | Update-GraphOAuthAccessToken -Force
```

When you disconnect you will want to export the AccessToken. This MUST be done each time.

```
$GraphAccessToken | Export-GraphOAuthAccessToken -Path 'c:\MyGraphApp\AccessToken.XML'
```

Connect to the Graph API and Get All Users

In this example we will use our token to connect to the Microsoft Graph API and get a list of our users. First, import the token

```
$GraphAccessToken = Import-GraphOAuthAccessToken -Path 'c:\MyGraphApp\AccessToken.XML'
$GraphAccessToken | Update-GraphOAuthAccessToken -Force
```

Next, we can get all of our users by running the following command:

```
Get-AADUserAll -AccessToken $GraphAccessToken
```